# Validation failed while upgrading Azure blob to DataLake Gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am upgrading Azure blob storage to DataLake Gen 2. I have already created a few pipelines in ADF in which there was a delete activity with logging enabled, and I have given a path to a blob container for the logged files.

Now when I tried to upgrade to DataLake Gen 2, validation failed saying that "Incompatible feature soft delete". I disabled "Enable Logging" in the ADF pipeline, removed the path of the blob folder and deleted that folder from blob storage. However I am still getting this validation failed message.

I am not able to get what changes are still needed. see the error: [image: error message]

Comment: Hi @Amar, if you are using the Azure blob storage linked service for your dataset, can you try creating an azure data lake gen2 dataset instead?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT thanks for reply but the concern is i am not having datalake right now , i am upgrading from blob to data lake and at that time i am getting this error in step 2 which is a validation step.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 8):

This question is answered in [Microsoft Q&A platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/845595/valiodation-failed-while-upgrading-azure-blob-to-d.html). Thank you @NandanHegde-7720 for the solution, posting it as an answer here to help the other community members.

Disable soft delete for containers in your storage account.

•   In the Azure portal, navigate to your storage account.

•   Locate the Data protection settings under Data management.

•   Uncheck soft delete for containers.

[image]

> Any soft-deleted containers will be permanently deleted at the expiration of the retention period that was in effect at the time that the container was deleted.

Refer to this link for more information on [how container soft delete works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-container-overview#how-container-soft-delete-works).

Alternatively, a quick workaround is to copy the files creating issues to the new storage account and then delete those files from the original storage account. Then try to upgrade `data lake gen2`.